# What is the worst-case PSRR of an LDO?

Tags: voltage-regulator, analog, ldo

For a low dropout regulator, what does the worst-case PSRR (power supply rejection ratio) mean?

I know what PSRR is, but I am not sure in what case the PSRR of LDO is the worst.

Thank you!

Comment: You know what PSR is. Fine, but In order to avoid any ambiguities, you should not use an acronym. Because on the other hand, we (or at least, I) don't know what it means. Could mean Primary Side Regulation, which doesn't make sense for a LDO. Or Power Supply Rejection Ratio, with a missing R. Please be explicit.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I am still a very immature student in analog circuit area so I have no idea what primary side regulation is. For my question, I am asking for the worst-case PSRR (power supply rejection ratio).

Comment: Please edit your original post to include this additional info. Some context would help too. Did you see this in a datasheet, in an exercise,...?

Comment: There is usually a graph (for all the major vendors, anyway) that show PSRR against frequency; it *always* gets worse moving away from DC and will go to some minimum value, but it can actually improve above that frequency. Specify a specific part and we could show you the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a LDO internal schematic from this [article](http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/ldo-regulators-unexpected-option-industrialiot-applications). It doesn't matter whether the pass device is a BJT or a FET, the mechanisms will be similar.

[image]

- **PSRR** is defined as the AC transfer function Vout/Vin for small variations of Vin. It is, of course, frequency-dependent, and it also depends on dropout voltage and current.
- **Dropout** is Vin-Vout.

When dropout is high enough, the pass transistor works well (in linear mode) and acts as a voltage-controlled current source, which helps to improve PSRR, as the current going through the transistor only depends on Vin due to second-order effects like Early effect or its FET equivalent. (You asked for a LDO, in an oldskool regulator where the pass transistor is an emitter/source follower, things are different).

However, as dropout voltage gets lower, the pass device gets squeezed between Vin and Vout, and will begin to operate in ohmic mode (for a FET) or in quasi-saturation (for a BJT).  Its transconductance will lower drastically. The increased capacitance will further degrade AC performance and increase gate drive current requirements.

At lower dropout voltage still, a PMOS becomes a simple resistor, and a BJT saturates. Its transconductance becomes zero, as it no longer responds to gate drive. The pass transistor is basically useless, and so is the error amp which at this moment is simply clipping, its output stuck to its limit. Regulators do clip, just like any opamp.

The LDO's control loop (error amp and pass device) adjusts the pass transistor's drive voltage to control the output voltage. More open loop gain results in more feedback around the loop, and thus more correction and better PSRR (along with lower output impedance and overall better transient responds). In fact, PSRR is proportional to open loop gain, and the important thing to note is that open loop gain is also proportional to the transconductance of the pass device.

The operation modes cases above correspond to very different transconductance values for the pass device, from maximum (transistor operating in linear mode) to low (FET in controlled resistor mode) to useless (FET is just its own RdsON).

Thus, PSRR degrades as dropout voltage gets lower. The worst case occurs just as the regulator's error amp clips and it loses regulation.

This also applies to most dynamic characteristics of the regulator: output impedance and transient response are dependent on the control loop gain, so they will also degrade when the pass transistor doesn't have enough dropout to work properly. This may also influence stability.

The dropout voltage when this transition occurs depends on current (higher current require larger dropout).

Additionally, the pass device has some parallel capacitance which increases as dropout gets lower (this is a characteristic of silicon capacitors) so HF PSRR will also suffer a bit at low dropouts. This isn't very important, but I'll mention in passing that larger transistors have larger capacitance, thus a 1A LDO will have more input-to-output capacitance than a 100mA LDO, for example.

[More details and nice graphs in this article.](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbva029/sbva029.pdf)

If you want realy worst-case, there may even be some corner cases where a regulator actually amplifies input ripple. For example, if it becomes unstable and oscillates.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to answer your question without context, but basically, the "worst case [anything]" is usually no more than what it literrally says: the worst value you could possibly have under the entire range of operating conditions guaranteed by the manufacturer.

The exact conditions under which this worst case can eventually be obtained is mostly irrelevant. It certainly is some combination of temperature range, supply voltage, variations of manufacturing conditions, etc... But when designing a product, except for very particular cases, you account for the worst case without considering in which conditions this may happen.

If you have very tight tolerances and need to know when this happens, your only option is to ask the manufacturer of the specific component you plan to use. Only him can tell, because it depends on the LDO internals.

Answer (score 0):

At DC, the internal electric fields in the LDO will not degrade PSRR.

At some frequencies, the electric fields WILL degrade the PSRR, as will matching of differential pairs and other silicon structures.

I recall an LDO with degraded performance at 1KHz and higher, thus Switching Regulator filtering was nil. Examining die photographs, we noticed the input metallization was placed adjacent to the feedback resistive divider network; seeing this basic silicon layout mistake is rather easy, given the metal and the resistors connect to package pins with well-defined functions. We acquired
some parts assembled in ceramic packages (this was many years ago) and found
the PSRR was 10dB better above 1KHz, because the "epoxy relative dielectric" was
replaced by the Eo=1 of air.